# Web3js get event logs with call (without sending real transaction)

Tags: evm, contract-debugging

I need to predict which event logs will be emitted by sending a transaction to my contract, but without sending a real transaction, for exemple by using the `call` method of my contract (using web3).

I know logs are written in the blockchain only when a real transaction is valided, and call doesn't write anythings but only read the blockchain.

But I also think that emit an event can be read by the EVM of my own node and so can be read when executing the call.

Is there any way to be notified of these events which "should have been emitted if the transaction was not just a simulation".
In bonus if I can see events even for a reverted transaction it can be so powerfull (I know it's a non-sense from the blockchain point of view but really usefull for debugging purpose).

No need for me to use web3js for this. If it's not possible like that, I'm also interested in documentation to for example tweek an ether node that would be able to do this (maybe pretentious, but I want to explore all possibilities).

Thanks you.